# Phonegap splash screen not loading

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm working on an application for Android using phonegap 3.5.0 - my testing device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab (GT-P5100) with Android 4.1.2 .

Half a year ago I did my first tests with phonegap. I remember the splashscreen loading at startup with the following line in the config.xml

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
```

Now with the hard- and software mentioned above it's not working anymore...

I tried the following:

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
```

and of course:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

P.S.: Not working on Sony Xperiia Z1 Android 4.4.4, too.

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap vesions above 3.5 require splashscreen plugin in order to load the splashscreen.You can  download from here (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/doc/index.md).
Also you can use native java code to display the splash screen

//splash.java

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //show your splash screen for three seconds
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            public void run() {
                    try{

                        sleep(3000);

                    }catch(InterruptedException e){

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }finally {

                    //launch the mainactivity after three seconds
                    Mainactivity.class  is your phonegap default javafile   
                    Intent mainactivity = new Intent(Splash.this,Mainactivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainactivity);               
   }
   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();

    }

}
```

NOTE:set Splash.java to launcher activity  and made appropriate changes in manifest file

Comment: what do you think what does the last code snippet mean in the OP's question? Anyway, 1.) this should be a comment, 2.) this is a link only answer.